# Display a link & page access based on requirements in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In an app using Java, SpringBoot, and Thymeleaf, can you make a Nav link that only shows up on Nav if they have certain info stored in database? I want a link to show up if the client's ams360Affiliate cell in the database is set to a certain option.

I don't think I can do something like this... any other ideas?

```html
sec:authorize="${client.ams360Affiliate== 'Access - AS & FOS only'} or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

```html
<ul style="margin-top:50px; min-height:35vh;">
  <li th:classappend="${currentPage == 'dashboard'} ? 'active'">
    <a th:href="@{/}"><img class="left" height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/menu_icons/speedometer.png" /> Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li th:classappend="${currentPage == 'resources'} ? 'active'">
    <a th:href="@{/resources}"><img class="left" height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/menu_icons/details.png" /> Resources</a>
  </li>
  <li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" th:classappend="${currentPage == 'administration'} ? 'active'">
    <a th:href="@{/admin}"><img class="left" height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/menu_icons/administrative-tools.png" /> Administration</a>
  </li>
  <li th:classappend="${currentPage == 'contactUs'} ? 'active'">
    <a th:href="@{/contactUs}"><img class="left" height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/menu_icons/contact.png" /> Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li th:authorize="${loggedUser.client.ams360Affiliate == 'Access – AS '\u0026' FOS Only'} or hasROle('ROLE_ADMIN')" th:classappend="${currentPage == 'directBind'} ? 'active'"><a th:href="@{/directBind}"><img class="left"  height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/menu_icons/dbForm.png"/> Direct Bind</a></li>
  </li>
  <li class="hide-on-large-only">
    <a th:href="@{/logout}"><img class="left" height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/menu_icons/shutdown.png" /> Logout</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use the th:if="..." attribute. That's sufficient to show or not-show a block. Add something to the model/session that indicates that ams360Affilate is set for the user and check  that in the th:if attribute.

Comment: @Flocke Can you please post your comment as answer? I don't like to read already answered question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the th:if="..." attribute. That's sufficient to show or not-to-show a block. Add something to the model/session that indicates that ams360Affilate is set for the user and check that in the th:if attribute.

e.g.:

```
<li th:if="${ams360AffiliateFlag || adminFlag}"..>...</>
```

Set both flags in the controller because (afaik) you can't use hasRole() in that kind of attributes. Therefore do something like this in your controller:

```
... MyController(HttpServletRequest request, ...)
{
   ...
   boolean adminFlag = request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
   ...
}
```